# How to see the Requests and Responses send by the Cloudfundy Java Client in the background (Api Mocking)

Tags: java, http, proxy, cloud-foundry

I am using the [Cloudfoundry Java Client](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client) to make a Rest-API with Spring Boot.
I want to test the endpoint by stubbing (e.g. with [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org)) the requests, which are send by the SDK in the background. For that, I need to get example-requests and -responses.

What I need to know is: When I call

```
{
//...
myCloudFoundryClient.organizations()
}
```

in the background the client does:

```
curl "https://api.my-domain.com/v2/organizations" -X GET
```

and then receives:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
{
   "some-json" : ...
}
```

I tried my usual Http-Proxys like the build-in Wiremock proxy and even Fiddler, but they don't seem to see those Requests.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the "Reactor"-implementation of the CF-Client uses Netty for HTTP. Netty however uses CONNECT for all requests. Wiremock can't handle that.
(https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/617#issuecomment-467012859)

The solution for me was switching to Hovercraft